# Trying to parse multiple lines from a textbox

Tags: c#, parsing

While this works for one line, i am trying to take multiple lines from the textbox "ProgramWindow" and run commands all of the commands typed one after another. in this case the commands draw shapes specified by the commands.
The commands can be in the following formats:

Command

Command Parameter

Command Parameter,Paramter

i have tried to use a loop but i am stuck at this point

```
String[] Lines = ProgramWindow.Text.Split('\n');
int NumberOfCommands = Lines.Length;
void Parse()
{    
     for (int i = 0; i <= NumberOfCommands; i++)
     {
            
                String[] Input = ProgramWindow.Text.ToLower().Split(' ', (char)StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                String Command = Input[0];
                int[] Parameters = Input.Length <= 1 ? new int[0] : Input[1].Split(',').Select(item => int.Parse(item)).ToArray();
                int X = Parameters.Length >= 1 ? Parameters[0] : 0;
                int Y = Parameters.Length >= 2 ? Parameters[1] : 0;
                Console.WriteLine(Command);
                Console.WriteLine(X);
                Console.WriteLine(Y);
                Commands(Command, X, Y);
                Refresh();
      }
}
```

Comment: The Lines are already in the TextBox properties. But I see no loop that would enumerate them/NumberOfCommands . Which btw has a silly name, imo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the Lines array

```
String[] Lines = ProgramWindow.Text.Split('\n');
int NumberOfCommands = Lines.Length;
void Parse()
{    
     for (int i = 0; i <= NumberOfCommands; i++)
     {
            
                String[] Input = Lines[i].ToLower().Split(' ', (char)StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                String Command = Input[0];
                int[] Parameters = Input.Length <= 1 ? new int[0] : Input[1].Split(',').Select(item => int.Parse(item)).ToArray();
                int X = Parameters.Length >= 1 ? Parameters[0] : 0;
                int Y = Parameters.Length >= 2 ? Parameters[1] : 0;
                Console.WriteLine(Command);
                Console.WriteLine(X);
                Console.WriteLine(Y);
                Commands(Command, X, Y);
                Refresh();
      }
}
```